# Remote Desktop Connection Fails - Error 0x204 or 0x104 through Mac on Vodafone Gigabox Router

Tags: router

Hi I'm trying to connect to my pc in work via my router which is a vodafone gigabox router - I'm on a mac and can connect when I use my mobile phone data - no issues - however when I try to connect via the vodafone home router - i get the error

Error code: 0x204   or

Error code: 0x104

in the gigabox settings I've tried prot mapping both for 3389 and 5900

Service Local IP Address    Protocol    Local Port  Public Port
TCP IP  TCP 3389-3390   3389-3390
UDP IP  UDP 3389-3390   3389-3390

Nothing works - please help me?? I'm lost -

Comment: I've also disabled the firewall - but no use

Comment: You're trying to get into it from the public internet?

Answer (score -1):

Simply switch from your wifi to mobile data or any other wifi. The problem occurs because the firewall disables the router's firewall. Check the link below for information about how to disable a router's firewall.

[Disable a Router's Firewall](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/663/%7E/how-to-disable-a-routers-firewall)

> 1. Log in to your router settings.
> 2. Search through your router menus and settings for phrases such as firewall, filter, or packet check. The terms and locations change
>    drastically from router to router. For example:
>
>    - D-Link: Look for *Firewall* under the *Advanced* menu.
>    - Netgear: Look for the *SPI Firewall* under the *WAN Settings* menu.
>    - Linksys: Look for *Firewall* or *SPI Firewall* within the *Security* menu.
>      *If your router has been provided by an ISP and has a custom UI, access to firewall settings may be restricted. If you find this access
>      has been restricted, you will need to contact your ISP for further
>      assistance.*
> 3. Choose the appropriate option to disable the firewall setting and *Save* or *Apply* the settings change.